# How can I POST without form in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm using dynamic fields for my input. I have a form with a submit button and div to append the dynamic fields. Right now I'm just trying to POST with dummy data, but I'll switch it to an array when it works.

```
<form class="signin" action="{% url 'main:link/link' %}" id="Form1">
```

This is my request in my html.

```
var $form = $( this ),
path = $form.attr( "action" );

payload = {"tKey":"test"};
var posting = $.ajax({
  url: path,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
  data: payload,
  dataType: "application-json",
});
console.log(payload);

posting.done(function() {
  console.log("posted");
});

posting.fail(function() {
console.log( "error" );
});
```

This is my views:

```
def test1(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, 'link.html')
elif request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.get('data')
    return render(request, 'link.html')
```

Unfortunately it keeps failing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it keeps failing?  Does it throw an exception?  What doesn't work?

Comment: It just keeps logging "error." Not really sure how else to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

if a view receives as an ajax call, it must deserialize the json body itself.

```
import json


def test1(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'link.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        return render(request, 'link.html')
```

Comment: data = json.loads(request.body) isn't working, was there something else to that? It keeps giving me a "inconsistent use of tabs" error.

Comment: If you're getting inconsistent use of tabs, that means you need to make sure you are either always using spaces for indents or always using tabs.   Pick one or the other.

Comment: That was actually really weird. I just cut it and pasted it back and it worked again. Unfortunately I'm still getting "error" logged when I submit